# iphone app release mode issue

Tags: iphone

i am about to launch app in app store,
i am trying to run code in release mode , i downloaded the **release mode profile** 
but when i compile code from iphone they say

**"A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."**

how to solve this pls help

##############  EDIT

now i can run release mode on my iphone  but i got this msg
**The program being debugged is not being run.**

**so now can i upload this release file to appstore???**
my setting

```
Code Sign Entitlements:Entitlements.plist
Code Sign Identity: my iphone dist release profile
any iphone dev: my iphone dist release profile
```

are these parameters sufficient to lauch app??

Comment: Have a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your connected device is provisioned through the iPhone Provisioning Portal. Check it's status by opening the Organiser in Xcode (Window -> Organizer) or press crtl + command + O.
Your iPhone will have to have a valid provisioning profile on an active iPhone developer account in order for you to run your app on your device.

However, running in Release mode and Device mode are different things, if you're trying to run in Device mode without a certified Device, that would cause this error. It wouldn't matter whether it was in Debug or Release mode though.

Comment: i cant see my release profile in organiser , i am about to launch my app , my debug mode was working fine, and will code run in release mode ??

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be trying to run in release mode. You can't actually do that, it would use the  Distribution provisioning profile which can't be installed on devices. (it's used for signing the code for App Store submission)

Create/install the Development profile (make sure you have the correct bundle and device list set) and set "code signing" for Debug to use that profile.

Comment: i want release file , so that i can uplaod that file to app store , how to get that , i can see relase file but i doubt since i got this error A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.

Comment: Oh, sorry. In that case, make sure you set "Code Signing" (for Release) to use your Distribution profile. If you have Xcode 4 you should be using "Archive" to build the project for submission.  -Edit: after seeing your reply to Bootle's answer, make sure you have both the Distribution provisioning profile and the Distribution _certificate_

Answer (score 0):

You can compile the code in release but you have to use a Certificate file that you have provisioned for the device. If you use the Distribution Certificate then you can only install the file through the normal distribution channels, (e.g. AppStore)

If you want to run your code in release on your device however you will sign it with the same Certificate you signed it with before. Only sign with the Distribution Cert if you are Uploading it to Apple.

**EDIT:**

Running in Release should be a fairly easy process.

Setup the project just like you would for debug.
Use the same signing certificate, and your developer profile.

Edit the selected scheme.

[image: Edit the Selected Scheme]

And Select Release rather than debug.
You may also want to change the Debugger to None

[image]

The rest of the settings should work the same as when you debug.

Therefore if you are using the Entitlements.plist when you run in debug, then you will use them when you run in release.

once again. (DO NOT USE DISTRIBUTION PROFILE)

[image]

Comment: and what about entilements.plst , do i need to add that also??

Comment: I am pretty sure I was deploying release code on my device, but I was signing it with the Developer Certificate.. Anything you have on your Application in Debug mode will be needed in release mode. I must apologize. I would test it on my device, but it was taken recently. As soon as I am able to get another I will test. But it should work. If not then please let me know. I will remove this post.